# Understanding initial state setting using react component lifecycle method

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react and as of now, I am trying to understand `lifecycle` methods.

I have a scenario in which the moment users logs in, the home page should display user specific data.
**So the moment user logs in I should set state of an application based on response from API(fetches user specific data).**
So I want to set state first (based on `response`) then render on real `DOM`. Now I thought I should use `getDeriveStatefromprops` for this purpose because it is just called before `render()`. So, I can call API and then set state then finally render. But I read that it is not recommended to cause side-effects(make api call etc.) in this method. So naturally I am left with `componentDidMound()`, where I can cause side effects.

> My question is if I want to first get API response then render based
> on that then why can't I use getDerivedStateFromProps, why I have to
> use componentDidMount?

> And what if fetch API call too much time, so will the initial render
> of home page will be based on initial state in constructor and when i
> get response back, then user specific data is displayed?

PS: I have researched a lot for around a day but couldn't get or understand the real reason for this. As I am new to react , a little less technical sounding answer is much appreciated.

Comment: It's ok to render before the API response, just make sure you render something that show a loading... message. Then, once the API responds, assign the response to a state variable and react will re-render with the proper info. I'm afraid you don't fully understand how React works.

Comment: @codemonkey, thanks, and why causing side effects in getderivedstatefromprops is not recommended?

Comment: Can you rephrase that question? I am not sure I understand what you mean by *why causing side effects in getderivedstatefromprops is not recommended*.

Comment: I mean why it is not recommended to make Fetch api calls in getDerivedStatefromProps?

Comment: Because that's not what it's for. The bottom line here is you want to get data from the API before you render ANYTHING. Why? Just render something that says "API data is loading" like a spinner.

Comment: Check out this Sandbox. It immediately renders something, but gets the API data 3 seconds later and only then renders what it gets from the API: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-brook-3ikhe?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @codemonkey, yes loader is the solution, and indeed that method is for state change as prop changes, because it literally says that. i was just curious to know that what if I call API in getDerivedStatefrom props, will that cause performance dip, or might break application due to some technical reason. But it turned out there is no such reason, its just that it is not meant for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use getDerivedStateFromProps, nobody forbids you to do that, but it's purpose is not for that. You should use it only for updating the internal state of the components depending on it's props changes. I would stick to componentDidMount, it's pretty good choice and the only one I see.

Comment: yes, i know it is meant to update state as props changes, because that's what the function name says, but my question was main towards why can't i cause side effects in getDerivedStatefromProps. but i actually can, but getDerivedStateFromProps may be called multiple times for a single update, so it's important to avoid any side-effects.